# what is retrieve and cache the system's default "short" animation time?

Tags: caching, animation, system, animatewithduration

I am trying to do a crossfade and the tutorial on Android Developers uses "animationDuration"
as the duration of the animation. Is this "animationDuration" supposed to be retrieved so that the duration of the fading animation is according to the processor's speed? I am new to android programming so simple things like this is still quite unfamiliar to me.

Here's the code:

public class CrossfadeActivity extends Activity {

```
private View mContentView;
private View mLoadingView;
private int AnimationDuration;

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crossfade);

    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.content);
    mLoadingView = findViewById(R.id.loading_spinner);

    // Initially hide the content view.
    mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Retrieve and cache the system's default "short" animation time.
    AnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(
            android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
}
```

Here's the animation class:

private void crossfade() {

```
// Set the content view to 0% opacity but visible, so that it is visible
// (but fully transparent) during the animation.
mContentView.setAlpha(0f);
mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// Animate the content view to 100% opacity, and clear any animation
// listener set on the view.
mContentView.animate()
        .alpha(1f)
        .setDuration(AnimationDuration)
        .setListener(null);

// Animate the loading view to 0% opacity. After the animation ends,
// set its visibility to GONE as an optimization step (it won't
// participate in layout passes, etc.)
mLoadingView.animate()
        .alpha(0f)
        .setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration)   //???
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use `android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime` [constant](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.integer.html#config_shortAnimTime).

```
int time = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
```

There also availbale `config_longAnimTime`, `config_mediumAnimTime` constants.